# como calcular diferencia de tiempos entre dos clientes

Tags: python, base-de-datos, pandas, numpy

Como puedo hacer para calcular la diferencia de tiempo entre las acciones de un cliente.

Quiero calcular todo el tiempo transcurrido de los usuarios hasta que pasa al siguiente usuario. ejemplo.... desde usuario 1 al dos transcurrió 2 días 4horas, 5 seg.

Este es el dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'usuario': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'Fecha': ['1990-01-02','1990-01-03','1990-01-04','1990-01-05','1990-01-08',\
                                  '1990-01-09','1990-01-10','1990-01-11','1990-01-12' ,'1990-01-15',\
                                  '1990-01-16', '1990-01-17', '1990-01-18','1990-01-19','1990-01-22',\
                                  '1990-01-23 ', '1990-01-24', '1990-01-25','1990-01-26','1990-01-29'],
                   'Hora': ['10:10:00','10:11:00','10:12:00','10:13:00','10:10:00',\
                                  '10:10:00','10:17:00','10:14:00','11:14:00','12:14:00',\
                                  '10:10:00', '10:20:00', '14:22:00','15:22:00','16:22:00',\
                                  '10:10:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00','00:00:00','00:00:00']})
```

Cada usuario tiene un evento, compra, visita producto , etc. como puedo sumar esos eventos por usuario. Por ejemplo, los eventos son entrar a la pagina, ver producto, esta en pagina principal, esta en pagina de compra, compra de producto. Obvio que cada uno de estos eventos en una fila diferente y quiero contar si el usuario hizo varias veces una acción... por ejemplo usuario 1 , entro 2 veces a la pagina principal, entro 2 veces a producto, compro 1 vez. (no tenerlo separado)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo primero sería añadirle al dataframe una nueva columna (que voy a llamar `timestamp`) que contenga la concatenación de tus columnas `Fecha` y `Hora`, convertidas a un `datetime` de python, pues una vez los tengamos así es posible hacer aritmética con fechas, como por ejemplo restarlas para obtener el tiempo transcurrido entre ellas.

```
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Fecha + " " + df.Hora)
```

Ahora podemos usar `df.groupby()` para que agrupe todas las filas de la tabla según el criterio que elijamos, y usaremos el usuario como criterio. El resultado de esa agrupación es un objeto, de momento no muy útil pues ni siquiera podemos mostrarlo, pero sobre el que podremos hacer otras operaciones:

```
g = df.groupby("usuario")
```

la agrupación `g` tendrá dos grupos (uno para cada usuario). Es posible hacer cálculos dentro de cada grupo (por ejemplo sumar números, hallar promedios). En este caso lo que queremos es tomar el campo `timestamp` de ese grupo y restar los valores máximo y mínimo dentro del grupo, pues esos corresponderán al último evento y al primero, y al restarlos tendremos la distancia temporal entre ellos.

Pandas no da una función específica para ello, pero podemos preparar una de forma muy sencilla. El parámetro `s` se entiende que es un dataframe con un grupo. La función retorna un dato que "resume" ese grupo.

```
def delta(s):
  return s.timestamp.max()-s.timestamp.min()
```

Basta aplicar esta función a la agrupación `g` para obtener lo que querías:

```
>>> g.apply(delta)
usuario
1   13 days 02:04:00
2   12 days 13:50:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

### Plus

(jajaja)

Ya que no das datos para esta parte, añadiré una columna con eventos aleatorios a modo de demo:

```
import random 
random.seed(1).  # Por reproducibilidad del ejemplo
df["evento"] = [random.choice(["entra", "sale", "ve", "compra"]) 
                for i in range(len(df))]
```

Esta parte es aún más fácil que antes! De nuevo usamos `groupby()`, esta vez agrupando por usuario y por evento. Lo que queremos hacer con cada grupo es simplemente contar cuántos elementos tiene. Pandas ya nos da `.count()` para eso. Por tanto:

```
>>> df.groupby(("usuario", "evento")).count()
                Fecha  Hora
usuario evento             
1       compra      4     4
        entra       3     3
        sale        2     2
        ve          1     1
2       compra      4     4
        entra       3     3
        sale        1     1
        ve          2     2
```

Donde se ve que el usuario 1 entra 3 veces, compra 4 (¡eso es consumismo!), etc.. Los títulos de las columnas "Fecha" y "Hora" son irrelevantes, puesto que no contienen ya fechas ni horas, sino el contador de eventos y obviamente ambas tienen el mismo número para ese contador, por lo que podemos quedarnos con una sola:

```
>>> df.groupby(("usuario", "evento")).count()["Fecha"]
usuario  evento
1        compra    4
         entra     3
         sale      2
         ve        1
2        compra    4
         entra     3
         sale      1
         ve        2
Name: Fecha, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Buenisimoooooooo la verdad la primera parte me re ayudo, la segunda (que tambien me dio ideas) tal vez me exprese mal yo . Imaginate que en vez de la columna fecha y hora, haya otras columnas que digan evento, evento1 , evento 2... asi hasta evento 10. y dentro de estas estaria nuevamente compra, entra sale (como cada paso que da en la pagina) , contar esos pasos por cliente quiero, usuario 1 hizo 2 entra, 4 sales, 1 ve, 0 compras por ejemplo.

Comment: @jlemosmusi Pues no te entiendo... Mejor será que plantees una pregunta nueva en la que tendrás más sitio para mostrar cómo es el dataframe que quieres procesar y un ejemplo del resultado que deseas.

Comment: tenes razon , mala mia me exprese super mal. ahi te escribo el ejemplo:
df = pd.DataFrame({'usuario': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                   'evento1': ["compra","entrepagina","inicio","veprod","veprod","veprod","inicio","compra","compra","compra","compra","veprod"]}). me gustaria saber por ejemplo. Usuario 1: compro 1 vez, entrepagina 1 vez, inicio 1 vez, veprod 1 vez.
Usuario2:veprod 2 veces, inicio 1 vez, compro 1 vez
Usuario3:compro 3 vecez, veprod 1 vez

Comment: @jlemosmusi Me refería a una nueva pregunta en el sitio, no en un comentario. En el comentario es imposible dar formato al código, y además seguramente la respuesta no me cabría en otro comentario. De todas formas, por lo que pones en este último comentario.. ¿no es precisamente esto lo que hice en la parte "Plus" de la respuesta? Yo no veo la diferencia.... Insisto en que mejor te explayas un poco en otra pregunta (no comentario)

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal? Tenes razon es mas claro con ejemplos. Mi idea es pasar de esto
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'usuario': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3],
                    'evento': ["compro","compro","viopag","viopag","entropag","compro","entropag","compro","salio","viopag","compro"]})

A esto
df3 = pd.DataFrame({ 'usuario' : [1,2,3],
                'compro' :[2,1,2],
                'viopag' :[1,1,1],
                'entropag' :[0,1,1],
                'salio' : [0,0,1]})