# Sumar eventos de usuarios en dif columnas

Tags: base-de-datos, pandas, data

Mi idea es pasar de esto

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'usuario': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3], 
                    'evento': ["compro","compro","viopag","viopag","entropag","compro","entropag",
                               "compro","salio","viopag","compro"]})
```

A esto

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({ 'usuario' : [1,2,3], 
                     'compro' :[2,1,2], 
                     'viopag' :[1,1,1], 
                     'entropag' :[0,1,1], 
                     'salio' : [0,0,1]})
```

Comment: Como te señalé en una respuesta a [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/216145/7123) la solución pasará por usar `group()`, aunque no de forma tan directa como en aquella otra pregunta. Intenta pensar una solución usando `group()` y muestranos lo que has llegado a conseguir, para que te ayudemos a partir de ahi. Las preguntas que no muestran algún intento no son bien recibidas.

Comment: Quizás [`pd.crosstab()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) puede ser más adecuado a este caso.